# Regular Expression remove Javascript String Continuation

Tags: regex

I have some javascript that isn't compiling in Google Closure because it has string continuation in it. I've tried to remove the slash and new line character with regular expressions but I can't get it to find between the talking marks.

Here is an example of the javascript:

```
var test = '<div class="pp_pic_holder"> \
<div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div> \
</div>';
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
preg_replace("/\\r?\n|\r/", "", $input_lines);
```

Comment: are you trying to parse js file in php?

Comment: I'm using php to merge all the javascript into a single file then running it through closure to compile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to find strings in javascript source-code, you have to also be able to find comments. Comments could contain quotation-marks, and strings could contain slashes.

The whole process is easiest done with two replacements:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '#//[^\\r\\n]*|/\\*.*?\\*/|("(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\'])*\')#s',
    function ($matches) {
        $str = $matches[1];

        // Return comments unmodified
        if (empty($str)) return $matches[0];

        // Remove line-continuations from strings:
        return preg_replace('#\\\\(?:\\r\\n?|\\n)#', '', $str);
    },
    $jscode);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/qcm8sB

Comment: This is an awesome answer and it works great at ideone.com.  I wan tto accept it however, I can't get it to run on my server. When I try I get memory errors like this: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4239074537 bytes). My server is runnning PHP 5.4.30

Comment: Ahh ha... adding a function handler and passing the function handler as a string solved my memory issue... 
function callback(){} 

$jscode = preg_replace_callback(
'...'
    "callback",
    $jscode
);